# How to build a windows/web application that stores data locally and sync's with remote database?

Tags: sql, winforms, offline

I am needing to build an application that stores data locally and then synchronizes with a remote MS SQL database.  I am not sure how to go about doing this.

1. Enter data offline on a form and store the data.
2. Synchronize the data with a remote MS SQL database when online.
3. There will be many users who enter data offline, the local database on each pc needs to update when online and grab the 30 most recent records for use offline.

Example: Each day users will enter data on their "form".  The users will be offline.  The users will return to the office and need to sync with the "online" database.  The next morning the users will need to sync with the online database before going offline.  They will need to have offline access to the 30 most recent records.  (They will use the 30 records for charting/graphing while they are offline)

I am very new to building apps.  I have VS 2010.  I am wondering where to start?  What language to use?  Is there a "framework" for doing this type of app?

Any info or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default.aspx and http://keithelder.net/blog/archive/2007/09/23/Sync-Services-for-SQL-Server-Compact-Edition-3.5-in-Visual.aspx